# Sending email with mail()

Tags: php, email, html-email

I'm making kind of email sender class and i have some problems:

- Some email services like russian mail.ru don't understand encoding of the message and show my UTF-8 mail in Windows-1251 charset. GMail is ok with that.
- All email services show text/html as plain text.
- Multipart messages broken as well.

Also i should note, that i'm sending it from local server build on OpenServer using GMail SMTP server.
My opinion problem in kind of *mybullshitcode* or in smth that covers Content-type header.

Theres a code:

```
class _EMAIL
{
    protected $type;
    protected $to;
    protected $subject;
    protected $plain;
    protected $html;
    protected $charset;
    protected $headers = array(
    'MIME-Version'  => '1.0',
    // 'Content-type'   => '',
    // 'From'           => '',
    // 'Cc'         => '',
    // 'Bcc'            => '',
    // 'Reply-To'       => '',
    // 'Subject'        => '',
    // 'Return-Path'    => ''
    );

    public function __construct($to, $subj, $datacharset, $sendcharset)
    {
        $this->to = self::hencode($to, $datacharset, $sendcharset);
        $this->subject = self::hencode($subj, $datacharset, $sendcharset);
        $this->headers['Subject'] = $this->subject;
        $this->datacharset = $datacharset;
        $this->sendcharset = $sendcharset;
    }
    public function setHeader($el, $val)
    {
        $this->headers[$el] = $val;
    }
    public function setPlain($message)
    {
        $this->plain = iconv($this->datacharset, $this->sendcharset, $message);
    }
    public function setHTML($message)
    {
        $this->html = iconv($this->datacharset, $this->sendcharset, $message);
    }


    /* Static */
    public static function send($to, $mail)
    {
        if ($mail->plain !== null && $mail->html !== null)
        {
            $r = sha1(uniqid());
            $mail->headers['Content-Type'] = "multipart/alternative; boundary=$r";
            $message = "--$r
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=".$mail->sendcharset."
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit

".$mail->plain."

--$r
Content-Type: text/html; charset=".$mail->sendcharset."
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit

".$mail->html."

--$r--";
        } else if ($mail->html !== null) {
            $mail->headers['Content-Type'] = 'text/html; charset='.$mail->sendcharset;
            $message = $mail->html;
        } else if ($mail->plain !== null) {
            $mail->headers['Content-Type'] = 'text/plain; charset='.$mail->sendcharset;
            $message = $mail->plain;
        } else {
            return FALSE;
        }
        $headers = '';
        $mail->to = $mail->to." <$to>";
        $mail->headers['X-Mailer'] = 'PHP/'.phpversion().' - Blabla '.Core::build_info();
        foreach ($mail->headers as $key=>$val)
        {
            $headers .= $key.': '.$val.'\r\n';
        }
        return mail($to, $mail->subject, $message, $headers);
    }

    private static function hencode($str, $data_charset, $send_charset=FALSE)
    {
        if ($send_charset && $data_charset != $send_charset)
        {
            $str = iconv($data_charset, $send_charset, $str);
        } else {
            $send_charset = $data_charset;
        }
        return '=?'.$send_charset.'?B?'.base64_encode($str).'?=';
    }
}
```

I tried to make `subj` and `to` headers in base64_encode - seems hopeless.

All kind of help will be appreciated!

**UPD: Quoted-printable variant**

```
    public function setPlain($message)
    {
        $this->plain = quoted_printable_encode(iconv($this->datacharset, $this->sendcharset, $message));
    }
    public function setHTML($message)
    {
        $this->html = quoted_printable_encode(iconv($this->datacharset, $this->sendcharset, $message));
    }

            $message = "--$r
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=".$mail->sendcharset."
Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable

".$mail->plain."

--$r
Content-Type: text/html; charset=".$mail->sendcharset."
Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable

".$mail->html."

--$r--";
```

**UPD2: Using PHPMailer...**
GMail email subject with cyrillic chars in end.

> Here is the subject. Ð­Ñ‚Ð¾ Ð·Ð°Ð³Ð¾Ð»Ð¾Ð²Ð¾Ðº!

The body is acceptable:

> This is the HTML message body in bold!. Такое сообщение!

Code:

```
$mail = new _EMAIL;
$mail->From = 'admin@ss133d.ru';
$mail->FromName = 'SS133D Administration';
$mail->addAddress($email, $login);
$mail->addReplyTo('admin@ss133d.ru', 'SS133D Administration');
$mail->isHTML(true);

$mail->Subject = 'Here is the subject. Это заголовок!';
$mail->Body    = 'This is the HTML message body <b>in bold!</b>. Такое <b>сообщение</b>!';
$mail->AltBody = 'This is the body in plain text for non-HTML mail clients. А это без HTML!';
```

So maybe i need to use iconv? Theres subj conversion UTF-8 to Windows-1252...

Comment: Any reason for not using existing libs?

Comment: Yep. Making my opensauce project build upon external libs can "hurt" me in future... So.. Only from scratch - only hardcore :D
Or theres smth build in PHP core after 5.3?

Comment: Well then go study the RFCs relevant to sending mails.

Comment: @RussianVodka You are like Cave Johnson :=)

Comment: @Andro47 [deal with it](https://encrypted-tbn3.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQamgywbXHkpXFaXBrJXWW8Tlap5oP198zY02QURKRqWMeTjYCd) :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you thought of using phpmailer [Here](http://github.com/phpmailer/phpmailer)

It does it all for you but requires to use your email and email password in config values. But its secure and your information wont be released so thats a option you could use.

Comment: K. I'll see it tommorow)

Comment: So ok! I tried to use PHPMailer in my project. See in upd2.

Comment: Ok. I changed iso encoding in phpmailer class to utf-8 and all works! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

According to http://otvet.mail.ru/question/92734494 you should do two things:

```
$headers[] = "Content-type: text/plain; charset=utf-8";
```

And set the encoding of html page to utf-8. So you should add the following as the first line in PHP code.

```
header('Content-type: text/plain; charset=utf-8');
```

According to [sending mail in UTF-8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7009648/sending-mail-in-utf-8) you should also use quoted_printable_encode() and have `Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable` instead of `Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit`

Comment: Emm... Don't get your point. I saw that answer... but...
Why should i make my HTML page to utf-8? First - i have my page in utf-8. Second - how does this relate to actual mail? 64base is better... i thought... And as you can see in my code - plain text ONLY message don't have that headers...

Comment: I cannot give you any logic for this. If it did not help then I will delete it.

Comment: Try `Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable` with function quoted_printable_encode()

Comment: Ok. I'll try it in next 10 mins.

Comment: Much greater!

<h1>=D0=97=D0=B4=D1=80=D0=B0=D0=B2=D1=81=D1=82=D0=B2=D1=83=D0=B9=D1=82=
=D0=B5, 2PTEST!.</h1>=D0=92=D0=B0=D1=88 E-mail =D0=B1=D1=8B=D0=BB =D1=83=
=D0=BA=D0=B0=D0=B7=D0=B0=D0=BD =D0=BF=D1=80=D0=B8 =D1=80=D0=B5=D0=B3=D0=
=B8=D1=81=D1=82=D1=80=D0=B0=D1=86=D0=B8=D0=B8 =D0=BD=D0=B0...

Comment: As much as u can see :) That's the result i get in GMail Plain+HTML

Comment: Can you output $message? is it originally in utf-8?

Comment: Yes. It's 100% in utf-8.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/54854/discussion-between-russianvodka-and-keiv-fly).